# view of numpy with 2D slicing

Tags: python, numpy, view, numpy-slicing

Numpy uses a view object to minimize memory copying. The code below slices the original ndarray using index list. The result is `None`, which means `arr[ [0, 3] ]` is allocated its own memory.

```py
arr = np.arange(5)
print(arr[ [0, 3] ].base)
```

In case of range slicing, `arr[0:2]` returns a view pointing to original ndarray (`[0 1 2 3 4]`)

```py
print(arr[ 0:2 ].base)
```

In case of 2D slicing, it works differently than I expected `None` to be printed out.

```py
arr = np.array([
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
])

print(arr[  : , [0, 2] ].base )
```

```
[[0 3 6]
 [2 5 8]]
```

I wonder why `None` wasn't returned and why shape of base wasn't (3, 2).

Answer (score 1):

```
In [205]: arr = np.array([
     ...:     [0, 1, 2],
     ...:     [3, 4, 5],
     ...:     [6, 7, 8],
     ...: ])
     ...: 
     ...: arr[  : , [0, 2] ]
Out[205]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [3, 5],
       [6, 8]])
```

The array indexing does what we expect. It's just the `base` that's different.

```
In [206]: _.base
Out[206]: 
array([[0, 3, 6],
       [2, 5, 8]])
```

I think this `base` gives clues as to the underlying process of the indexing.  It made a copy with the `[0,2]` advanced indexing, and performed some sort of transpose to return the desired array.

I haven't paid whole lot of attention to `base`.  If there's doubt about whether something is a view or not, I like to compare the `__array_interface__`
.

Usually it's enough to know that the `data` value is clearly different (and not just an offset).

```
In [209]: arr.__array_interface__
Out[209]: 
{'data': (38026368, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (3, 3),
 'version': 3}
In [210]: arr[  : , [0, 2] ].__array_interface__
Out[210]: 
{'data': (38386288, False),
 'strides': (8, 24),
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (3, 2),
 'version': 3}
```

Looking further at the `strides`:

```
In [218]: arr.strides
Out[218]: (24, 8)
In [219]: arr[:,[0,2]].strides
Out[219]: (8, 24)
In [220]: arr[:,[0,2]].copy().strides
Out[220]: (16, 8)
```

`arr` strides is `(3*8, 8)`, since stepping to the next row means skipping 3 column values.  But the indexed strides are reversed, which is what I'd expect from the transpose of its `base`.  The full copy is `(2*8,8)` reflecting the 2 column shape.

So here `base` is revealing details of the indexing process.  I haven't noticed those before, and I've been using `numpy` for quite some time.

---

Another case where `base` reflects the construction process, is making your `arr` via `arange`:

```
In [213]: np.arange(9).reshape(3,3).base
Out[213]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

That `base` comes from the `arange`, yet we never assigned to a variable.