# How is multidimensional array slicing/indexing implemented in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

One of the great feature of NumPy arrays is that you can perform multidimensional slicing. I am wondering exactly how it is implemented. Let me lay out what I am thinking so far, then hopefully someone can fill in the gaps, answer some questions I have, and (probably) tell me why I'm wrong.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] ])

# retrieve the rightmost column of values for all rows
print(arr[:, 2])

# indexing a normal multidimensional list
not_an_arr = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] ]  
print(not_an_arr[:, 2])  # TypeError: indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

At first, `[:, 2]` seemed like a violation of Python syntax to me. If I tried to index a normal multidimensional list in Python I would get an error. Of course, upon *actually reading the error message*, I realize that the issue isn't with the syntax as I originally thought, but the type of object passed in. So the conclusion I've come to is that `[:, 2]` implicitly creates a tuple, so that what's really happening in `[:, 2]` is `[(:, 2)]`. **Is that what's happening?**

I next tried to read the source code for the `numpy.ndarray` class which is [linked to](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.21.0/numpy/core/src/multiarray/arrayobject.c) by the [ndarray documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html?highlight=ndarray#numpy.ndarray), but that's all in C, which I'm not proficient in, so I can't make much sense of this.

I then noticed that there was [documentation for `ndarray.__getitem__`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.__getitem__.html). I was hoping this would lead me to the implementation of `__getitem__` for the class, since my understanding is that implementing `__getitem__` is where the behavior for indexing an object should be defined. My hope was that I would be able to see that they unpack the tuple and then use the slice objects or integers included in it to do the indexing on the underlying data structure however that may need to be done.

**So... what really goes on behind the scenes to make multidimensional slicing work on numpy arrays?**

*TLDR: How is multidimensional array slicing implemented for numpy arrays?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can verify your first level inferences with a simple class:

```
In [137]: class Foo():
     ...:     def __getitem__(self,arg):
     ...:         print(arg)
     ...:         return None
     ...: 
In [138]: f=Foo()
In [139]: f[1]
1
In [140]: f[::3]
slice(None, None, 3)
In [141]: f[,]
  File "<ipython-input-141-d115e3c638fb>", line 1
    f[,]
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

In [142]: f[:,]
(slice(None, None, None),)
In [143]: f[:,:3,[1,2,3]]
(slice(None, None, None), slice(None, 3, None), [1, 2, 3])
```

`numpy` uses code like this in `np.lib.index_tricks.py` to implement "functions" like `np.r_` and `np.s_`.  They are actually class instances that  use an index syntax.

It's worth noting that it's the comma, most so than the `()` that creates a tuple:

```
In [145]: 1,
Out[145]: (1,)
In [146]: 1,2
Out[146]: (1, 2)
In [147]: ()          # exception - empty tuple, no comma
Out[147]: ()
```

That explains the syntax.  But the implementation details are left up to the object class.  `list` (and other sequences like `string`) can work with integers and `slice` objects, but give an error when given a tuple.

`numpy` is happy with the tuple.  In fact passing a tuple via `getitem` was added years ago to base Python because `numpy` needed it.  No base classes use it (that I know of); but user classes can accept a tuple, as my example shows.

As for the `numpy` details, that requires some knowledge of `numpy` array storage, including the role of the `shape`, `strides` and data-buffer.  I'm not sure if I want get into those now.

A few days ago I explored one example of multidimensional indexing, and discovered some nuances that I wasn't aware of (or ever seen documented)

[view of numpy with 2D slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68235528/view-of-numpy-with-2d-slicing)

For most of us, understanding the how-to of indexing is more important than knowing the implementation details.  I suspect there are textbooks, papers and even Wiki pages that describe 'strided' multidimensional indexing.  `numpy` isn't the only place that uses it.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html

This looks like a nice intro to numpy arrays

https://ajcr.net/stride-guide-part-1/